# How should typescript module augmentations be properly imported/included into an angular library or application?

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules

I have found many examples on how to setup module augmentation files for adding functionality to a node_module, but I'm a little confused on how they should be included in the typescript compilation. Should I just import the file that does the augmentation at the top of `main.ts` (or `public_api.ts` for a library) like this:

```
import './moduleaugmentationfile';
```

Or is there some other standard way to make this added functionality available across the application.

**Edit:**
[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-example-module-augmentation) is an example app. The example module augmentation is in `moduleaugmentation.ts`. I added a comment in the `main.ts` that explains my confusion about how best to include the module augmentation.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more - what is your concrete problem and code?

Comment: @ford04 I added an example that seems to work, but since I haven't found any documentation on the best way to do this, I'm not confident that it's the recommended way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example looks good, this is also the proper way to [augment a module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

Module augmentation = there is already a type declaration of a given npm package provided by the package maintainers, which you want to extend. The important thing here is to have an `export`/`import` at the top level to assign the file to module scope, otherwise the compiler would expect an [ambient module declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) (no existent type definition of a package).

There should be no need to manually include the type definitions manually (I think in the past, that could be done with [triple slash directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html), you don't use `import` for global declarations). Nowadays the compiler uses [Automatic inclusion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details) (though I am not exactly sure concerning different Angular configurations):

> If the "files" and "include" are both left unspecified, the compiler defaults to including all TypeScript (.ts, .d.ts and .tsx) files in the containing directory and subdirectories except those excluded using the "exclude" property.

Some last hint on RxJS usage:
You can import `Observable` directly from the package root (see [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.x/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#import-paths) for an example in the RxJS v6 docs), e.g.

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs"
```

, so you don't have to rely on package internals.

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs"

declare module "rxjs" {
  interface Observable<T> {
    subscribeAndLog: (a: string) => void
  }
}
```

Cheers, hope it helps.

Comment: So in my example, I put the import in the main.ts, but what about for an angular library

Comment: I'm thinking just putting the import at the top of public-api.t fro the library, instead of main.ts for the application will work.

Comment: Vanilla TS automatically collects all global declarations/augmentations in the project root indicated by a `tsconfig.json`, so there is no need to import anything manually here. Though I am no Angular expert, If I remove `import './moduleaugmentation'` in `main.ts` of your Angular sample, it still compiles, so that is a sign that automatic inclusion of `moduleaugmentation.ts` kicks in.

Comment: if you look at the console though, it is throwing an error at runtime when you comment out the import, so it does automatically collect that augmentation. Also, I created a similar project on my local machine, and it doesn't even build, so I'm not sure exactly why it appears to build on stackblitz. I'm guessing there's just some differences in the build config that I overlooked.

Comment: I ended up just downloading the project from stackblitz. If I take out my import of the moduleaugmentation, then it does compile locally, and it has the same issue where it just throws an error at runtime.

Comment: My bad - I overlooked that you also extend the javascript prototype in the same file, so there is not only the module augmentation, but runtime code contained.  Of course, this file has to be imported then. In theory, you could separate the module augmentation and prototype extension in different files, the former type would be automatically included then, the latter would have to be imported.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're saying now. It appears to be picking up the augmentation of the type properly, which allows it to compile, but it's obviously not running the code to update the prototype.

Comment: Yeah exactly! So, you could treat `moduleaugmentationfile.ts` just as polyfill import in your top main file. The types would be caught in every case.