# Add method to custom existing class from custom library in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class `FileData` from a custom library:

```
export class FileData {
  public name: string;
  public data: string;

  constructor(name: string, data: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

I import the library in my app and wanted to add a clone method to it because I need a deep copy of a complex object (please note, the actual class is a bit more complex and this is not the only class I add a clone method to it). Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61485387/2139555) to basically the same question but for typescript I added this code to my app in a separate file within my shared module, `src/app/shared/models/extensions/file-data.ts`:

```
import { FileData } from 'mat-fileupload';

declare module 'mat-fileupload' {
  interface FileData {
    clone(): FileData;
  }
}
if (!FileData.prototype.clone) {
  Object.defineProperty(FileData.prototype,
                        'clone',
                        { enumerable: false,
                          writable: false,
                          configurable: false,
                          value: function clone(this: FileData): FileData {
                            return new FileData(this.name, this.data);
                          } });
}
```

And in the class I use it:

```
import { FileData } from 'mat-fileupload';

export class Record extends DataEntry {
  ... // Other properties
  public img?: FileData;
  
  constructor(..., img?: FileData) {
    ... // Other initializations
    this.img = img;
  }

  public clone(): void {
    return new Record(..., img?.clone());
  }
}
```

The typescript compiler in VS Code seems to be happy about this and doesn't complain. However, if I run `ng build` or `ng serve` the angular compiler complains:

> **error TS2339: Property 'clone' does not exist on type 'FileData'.**

Sure, technically all of this is my own code and I could just add the clone method to my library but I would like to keep responsibilities separate and the creation of a deep copy is an issue in my app, not in the library, which is only responsible for uploading a file.

So how can I add my clone method to the existing `FileData` class?

**EDIT:**

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019396/how-should-typescript-module-augmentations-be-properly-imported-included-into-an) asking on how to import a typescript module augmentation in an angular app. I've also modified the included stackblitz slightly, [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-example-module-augmentation-qiywzl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmoduleaugmentation.ts). Notice that this works both in the stackblitz and, if I include this in my app, it also works there. So, if I can easily extend the `Observable` class from `rxjs` and add a method to it, it **must** also be possible to somehow add a method to my own `FileData` class.

Yet, if I do the same with the `FileData`:

observable.ts:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

declare module 'rxjs' {
  interface Observable<T> {
    subscribeAndLog<T>(this: Observable<T>,
                       next?: (value: T) => void,
                       error?: (error: any) => void,
                       complete?: () => void): Subscription;
  }
}
// This works!
Observable.prototype.subscribeAndLog = function <T>(this: Observable<T>,
                                                    next?: (value: T) => void,
                                                    error?: (error: any) => void,
                                                    complete?: () => void): Subscription {
  console.log('Subscribing to Observable');
  const sub = this.subscribe(next, error, complete);
  return sub;
};
```

file-data.ts:

```
import { FileData } from 'mat-fileupload';

declare module 'mat-fileupload' {
  interface FileData {
    clone(this: FileData): FileData;
  }
}
// 'FileData' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
// Why is this different? What does that error message even mean?
FileData.prototype.clone = function(this: FileData): FileData {
  return new FileData(this.name, this.data);
};
```

main.ts:

```
import './app/shared/models/extensions/file-data';
import './app/shared/models/extensions/observable';
```

record.ts:

```
public clone(): Record {
  of(1).subscribeAndLog(); // This works!
  return new Record(..., this.img?.clone());
}
```

Note that still, the Typescript compiler is perfectly fine with this, only the angular compiler complains. How can I tell angular to use `FileData` the same as `Observable`?

Comment: This is a lot of code.

Comment: @possum Nah. Half of it is basically the same, just try and error with minor adjustments.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution for your case is extend the class with method(s) you need and use this class instead of one you have from the library:

```
export class Record extends FileData {
  constructor(...) {super(...);}
  clone(this: Record ): Record;
}
```

The issue you has appears in next cases:

1. You haven't informed your libraby that it should use your class instead of default one.
2. After clonning you return `FileData` instead of `Record` which won't allow you clone object after clonning.

Or you can simply create function which you will import anywhere you want to clone anything:

```
export function cloneAnything<T>(anyTypeValue: T): T {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(anyTypeValue)) // as T (if you have typescript errors)
}
```

Comment: Hold up. The clone method of the `FileData` class returns a `FileData` object. The clone method of the `Record` returns a `Record` object. I do not return a `FileData` instead of a `Record`, so your 2. isn't correct.

Comment: I need a deep copy of my `Record` object, and this object has a `FileData` property, which means I need to copy that as well. Otherwise I get left with a reference to the same `FileData` object inside of my cloned `Record`. The `Record`'s clone method does that internally inside of its own clone method so from the outside, all I have to call is the `Record`'s clone method and get a deep copy because the `Record` calls the clone of its own object properties. The `Record` cannot and should not extend from the `FileData`.

Comment: 1. is my actual issue, and that's basically the whole question. How do I tell angular to combine the `FileData` class definition of the library with the clone method I defined in my app?

Comment: The is no such an option (if the class from the library isn't static). That's why I wrote what I wrote. I didn't wrote how to make deep clonning beacuse I thought you already has the clone method and just don't know how to attach it (and there are many articles about deep clonning, so I don't think this topic worth to be discussed here).  So in any case you need class which extends `FileData` (in the exaple named `Record`) and work with it everywhere where you need your clone function.

Comment: And simplest option for this is inform your library what class to you (personally I know only one library which provides such an option, and it is not free). The most common situation is to create wrapper for your componenet which will return you `Record` instear of `FileData` anytime you need it.

Comment: Then you shouldn't name it `Record` of all names, as I'm already using that class name in my app. Made me think you had something confused there with the classes I'm using for deep cloning. No, deep cloning doesn't need to be discussed, that isn't what this question is about anyway.

Comment: Also, I've found a different question trying to modify the `Observable` class of rxjs, which worked. So it must also be possible for me to modify my own class for this to work. I'm editing the question.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I don't know such a way in Angular. Of course you can use typescript ignore and and do whatever you want in JS but I wouldn't recommend it. I've updated my responce with one more solution which in my opinion is relevent for you. Sorry if my response disappointed you. If you think it is not valuable I can remove it.

Comment: You can leave the response, after all, extending `FileData` is an option to get the clone method in my app. Even though it isn't an answer to the actual question on how to get a method into an existing class. Btw, I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: I've edited the question. There's a link to the stackblitz.

Comment: Oh, good article. I'd expect using prototypes, but didn't know tha it is possible so easy. Considering that looks like you did everything well. So I think the problem relates to the angular module handling. At first clear folder `.angular`, it caches everything, so your updated might not be considered because of that. Then check the module resolution order and the imports order, you module extencion must be before any using of the clone method. At last check your `angular.json` to to ensure that the files the code are included in the build process and are not excluded or ignored.

Comment: Deleting the `.angular` folder didn't help, the error remains the same after running `ng build`. I'm using `import '..../file-data';` before `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)` in the `main.ts`. Since this is the same spot I import the `observable.ts`, I would assume it's the right place? Where exactly would I find included/excluded files in the 'angular.json'? I don't see anything like that in the `"build": { ... }` section, besides `"stylePreprocessorOptions": { "includePaths": [...] }` but those only contain some `node_modules` subfolders and only concern styles anyway.

Comment: I thought about `polyfills` or `scripts` arrays, but after making some research it doesn't look like good solution, usually `tsconfig.json` is enough.  So at first check if it is include the file and to be sure assignement called immediately wrap your `if` statement into selfcalled function (IIFE). If it won't help to fix compiler error must work wrapping the `if` statement into function which will be called in a `constructor` of provided in `root` service.

Comment: What kind of statement do I have to look out for in the tsconfig.json? I see neither anything with **include** nor **exclude** in the build section. What do you mean with `if` statement? I have no if statement anywhere regarding this code.

Comment: I mean this line at the top level of `tsconfig.json` object: `"include": ["src/**/*.ts"],` because such declaration won't be included by default if you don't import and call function from it explicitly.